# What does the bandwidth of a medium even mean?

Tags: bandwidth, multiplexing

> Whenever the bandwidth **of a medium** linking two devices is greater than
> the bandwidth needs of the devices, the link can be shared.
> Multiplexing is the set of techniques ...

Forouzan, Data Communications, p. 156

I always knew that bandwidth is always of a signal. Composite signals (made of many simple sine signals) are made up of different frequencies. The difference between the highest and the lowest frequency is the bandwidth of that composite **signal**. Now, in the above quote, the author talks about the bandwidth of a **medium**. What does that even mean? How can a medium have a bandwidth? I also do not think that the author is talking about the bandwidth that is measured in bps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the version of the book I found, Forouzan gives a good example:

[image: Modulation is needed if the medium is bandpass in nature or if only a bandpass channel is available to us. An example is radio. The government assigns a narrow bandwidth to each radio station. The analog signal produced by each station is a low-pass signal, all in the same range. To be able to listen to different stations, the low-pass signals need to be shifted, each to a different range.]

---

> Can't signals of any bandwidth/frequency pass through any medium?

Well, you can try... but it might not work.

Suppose you have a baseband signal that has a spectrum indicated in the figure below by the orange triangle, $\color{orange}{X(f)}$. Also suppose you want to pass it through the bandpass channel indicated by the light tan rectangles, $\color{brown}{H(f)}$.

The output of trying to do that without modulation is:

$$
Y(f) = \color{orange}{X(f)} \cdot \color{brown}{H(f)} = 0
$$

so nothing sensible comes out of the channel.

That's why we need modulation: to match the bandwidth of the signal with the bandwidth of the channel.

[image: Baseband signal and a bandpass channel.]

Comment: So, different mediums/links/channels also have a bandwidth associated with them? I am just a bit foggy about the mechanism of how a medium/link/channel has a bandwidth. This might be a stupid question, but can't signals of any bandwidth/frequency pass through any medium?

Comment: You should _edit your question_ to reflect this confusion.  In the mean time, reflect on the frequency range of signals you might be able to get from point A to point B with two tin cans and a string, with a length of twisted-pair telephone cable, and with a length of high-quality coax cable.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic I've illustrated the example given in the text book. Perhaps that makes things clearer.

Comment: I had an additional question. If the baseband signal modulates a carrier signal of a higher bandwidth range, then the bandpass channel will act as a filter to the signal, right? The width of the channel is less than the width of the signal.